# MySql Triggers - Can a trigger stop ALL dml?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to create a trigger on a table that is initiated when ANY dml is performed on the table?

For example -- I need to ensure that no insert/update/delete statements can be run on the weekend.  So, instead of writing:

CREATE TRIGGER DENY_DML_1 BEFORE INSERT...

CREATE TRIGGER DENY_DML_2 BEFORE UPDATE...

CREATE TRIGGER DENY_DML_3 BEFORE DELETE...

...is it possible to write one trigger to rule them all?

Many thanks in advance!
~Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

> *trigger_event* indicates the kind of
>   statement that activates the trigger.
>   The *trigger_event* can be one of the
>   following:  **INSERT**...  **UPDATE**... 
>   **DELETE**...

Comment: Thank you for confirming.  I was pretty sure I was going to have to write a trig for each event, but I thought I'd get community feedback before going the extra mile.  Thank you!